# I need an Access query that returns customer orders where more than 1 product type was purchased.

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I thought this would be simple enough, I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322322/using-sql-query-to-find-details-of-customers-who-ordered-x-types-of-products), but can't get it to work Count(Distinct) doesn't work in access apparently.  So here's my relevant structure:

tblMaster with fields ID (Primary Key), fldOrderNumber, ProductID, and fldPurchaseDate

tblProduct with field ProductID (key) and fldProductName.

Certain order numbers will have multiple productID entries; so if someone bought 3 products in one order, there will be 3 rows in tblMaster with the same fldOrderNumber, but with a different ProductID in each row.  I need a query that only returns those fldOrderNumbers.....so basically non-unique fldOrderNumbers.

Answer (score 1):

I can't currently think of a simpler version than this. This could be quite slow for larger tables.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM 
    tblMaster AS A 
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            fldOrderNumber, 
            COUNT(*) AS [Count] 
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    fldOrderNumber, 
                    ProductID
                FROM 
                    tblMaster
            )
        GROUP BY 
            fldOrderNumber
    ) AS B 
ON 
    A.fldOrderNumber = B.fldOrderNumber
WHERE 
    B.Count > 1;
```